# editActionsForRowAtIndexPath not called, both commit editingStyle and canEditRowAt present

Tags: swift, tableview, ios10, uitableview

I am trying to add a second swipe button to my table view rows, but `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` is not being called when I swipe a row. This is despite my class declaring both

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

    return true
}
```

and

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

}
```

Both of these are called when I swipe because I also have a regular delete button.

My `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` function is written as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewRowAction? {

    print("triggered!")

    let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "More") { action, index in
        print("more button tapped")
    }
    more.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    return more
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your `tableView`'s `delegate` property set?

Comment: I had the same problem and @Aaron's answer worked for me. I accidently removed tableView's delegate from the class.

Comment: If anyone else is experiencing this issue for another reason, please note this delegate call is made when the user actually swipes the tableView row rather than when the tableView reloadData is called.  Make sure nothing is covering the tableView preventing the swipe from occurring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the updated Swift 3 API for this particular method. The delegate method should be written as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    print("triggered!")

    let more = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "More") { action, index in
        print("more button tapped")
    }
    more.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    return [more]
}
```

Comment: You've made my mistake clear: your code does not work, but it's close: I was missing brackets in my return value, [ more ]. Care to explain why no brackets on either does not work?

Comment: @rodrigochousal

`more` is a single action, while [more] is an array of actions.